# Delete old files from git repo

Tags: git, repository, gitlab

is there a possibility to remove old files and folders from the complete GIT repository (also in all commits)?
I´m using GIT 1.9 and Gitlab 6.8.

Comment: By old files, do you mean ones that you removed already and are showing up, or in what context specifically?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4987341/completely-remove-old-git-commits-from-history

Comment: No i don´t want to remove complete commits, I wan´t to remove for example compiled source-code (*.dll and *.exe files) from all commits to shrink the size of my repository.